# It's it better to use mineral water or distilled water for my mash when making vodka?

Tags: water

I'm asking which type of water is best for making a mash to distill down to a vodka? Distilled water or bottled mineral water?

Comment: You might get a faster and better answer if you post the question on the Homebrewing SE site.

Comment: I thought this was the home brewing site.

Comment: This site is about purchased beer, wine and spirits. There is a separate stack exchange site for home brewers. You aren’t the first person confused by this.

Comment: Thank you,  I shall take my question to it's rightful place.

Comment: Admins can we close this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used, and distilled water and mineral. The output will be different taste. Distilled water gives a softer taste.

Comment: Thankyou. Interesting.

Comment: The first sentence is ungrammatical. Perhaps you mean to say: “Either distilled or mineral water can be used.”